# Questions about two proofs for showing $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ is finite, without using concept of norm for gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, gaussian-integers

*Background:*

**Theorem 6.6**  Let $I$ be an ideal in a ring $R$ and let $a,c\in R,$ Then $a\equiv c \pmod I$ if and only if $a+I=c+I.$

**Theorem 10.8** Every Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain.

**Exercise 15:** Let $I$  be a nonzero ideal ini $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, show that the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ is finite.

> Proof 1: By Theorem 10.8 $I=(b)$ for some nonzero $b.$  If $a\in \mathbb{Z}[i],$ then $a=bq+r$ with $r=0$ or $\delta(r)<\delta(b),$ and, hence, $a\equiv  r \pmod I.$    By Theorem 6.6, the number of distincct cosets of $I$ (congruence classes mod $I$) is at most the number of possible $r$'s under division by $b.$   Show that there are only finitely many possible $r$'s.

> Proof 2: Say $I=\langle a+bi \rangle.$  Then $a^2+b^2+I=(a+bi)(a-bi)+I=I$ and therefore $a^2 +b^2\in I.$  For any $c,d\in \mathbb{Z},$ let $c=q_1(a^2+b^2)+r_1$ and $d=q_2(a^2+b^2)+r_2,$ where $0\leq r_1,r_2<a^2+b^2.$  Then $c+di+I=r_1+r_2i+I.$

*Questions:*

I have a few related questions for the two proofs above to the quoted exercise. In proof 1, I don't understand when it says "the number of distinct cosets of $I$ (congruence classes mod $I$) is at most the number of possible $r$'s under division by $b.$"  Is the author saying that I am suppose to count the number of equivalence classes?  Because it asks the reader to show that there can only be finitely many $r$s.  But in proof 2, I am not sure why it need to use two separate integers $c,d$ with respect to $(a^2+b^2)$ in order to use the division algorith twice to show that there are two remainders $r_1, r_2$ and that they are used to satisfy Theorem 6.6.  How is that showing there are only two $r'$s?  I mean why only two integers, or does it mean that any more would imply that the extra ones would go into one of the two equivalence classes $[c],[d]$?  (here i am using the notation $[c]$ to denote equivalence classes).  Also when this question came up in the text, the notion of norm for gaussian integers has not been introduced yet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If $a + I$ and $c + I$ are distinct cosets, then $a \not\equiv c \pmod{I}$ by the first theorem. Since an element is equivalent to its remainder modulo $I$, we have $a \equiv r_a \pmod{I}$ and $c \equiv r_c \pmod{I}$, implying that $r_a \not\equiv r_c \pmod{I}$.

This means the map taking an element $x$ to its remainder $r_x$ is injective. The number of possible remainders is finite, since we must have $\delta(r) < \delta(b)$, and the number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with norm less than $\delta(b)$ is finite.

---

The second proof is completely different. It says that the norm of $a+bi$ is an element of $I$, so one may perform Euclidean division with $a^2+b^2$ to write any element as $r_1 + r_2i$ where $0 \leq r_1, r_2 < a^2+b^2$.

For example, if $I = \langle 3+ 4i \rangle$, then $25 \in I$. Then if you gave me an arbitrary coset, like $(102 + 264i) + I$, I would simply tell you that $102 + 264i \equiv 2 + 14i \pmod{I}$, and hence the coset you gave me is actually equivalent to $(2 + 14i) + I$.

There would then be at most (this is overestimating) $25 \times 25$ possible cosets.

Comment: @OrangeMusroom for the first proof, when you said "the number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with norm less than $\delta(b)$ is finite." basically we don't care what the $\delta$ is suppose to be, only that $\delta(b)$ is finite.  Is that correct?

Comment: for the second proof,, $102 + 264i \equiv 2 + 14i \pmod{I}$ means that $102 + 264i - (2 + 14i) + I=100+250i+I\in I$ but since the norm of $\langle 3+ 4i \rangle$ is $25$, then $25\mid 100, 25\mid 250$, but how do you get $25\times 25$ cosets?